# Connected database not updating

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have connected my SQL database to my aspx.net form but when I entered the details in the form, it does not seem to update in my SQL Table. I've checked the codes and there doesn't seem to be any errors. Could anyone see what's wrong with my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;


public partial class CustomerLogin : System.Web.UI.Page {
    public string sqlTest = "Data Source=TEAFAMILY;Initial Catalog=Bolsen;Integrated Security=True";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    static readonly string scriptSuccessNewAccount =
    "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
        "alert (\"Your account has been succesfully created - Thank You!\");\n" +
    "</script>";


    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SqlConnection mDB = new SqlConnection(sqlTest);
        mDB.Open();
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader rdr;
        string strSQLSelect = "SELECT cEmail FROM Customers ORDER BY cEmail";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
        Console.Write(cmd);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //insert new record
        string strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO"
            + " Customers (cFirstname, cLastname, cNumber, cCompanyname, cAdd, cEmail, cPassword)"
            + " VALUES (@FN, @LN, @Num, @Cname, @Add, @Email, @Pw)";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLInsert, mDB);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", txtFN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", txtLN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", txtPN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cname", txtComp.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", txtCompAdd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pw", txtPW.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mDB.Close();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Success", scriptSuccessNewAccount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a try / catch in order to catch an Exception from `ExecuteNonQuery()` ?

Comment: How are you validating? Are you sure you're connected to the same database, on the same instance, and that none of your connection strings use the `User Instances` or `AttachDbFileName` attributes?

Comment: what's with the rdr, you never perform a .Read and you don't appear to be trying to use anything from it. Have you set a breakpoint in this code to ensure that it's actually running?  And if it is, step down through it and hover over the text properties to see what they hold.

Comment: What does a profiler trace show when you run the app?

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your `SqlDataReader`. Asides from not calling `rdr.Read()` and getting any values, you need to call `rdr.Close()` before executing your second sql statement.

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) - *While the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is busy serving the SqlDataReader, and no other operations can be performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it. This is the case until the Close method of the SqlDataReader is called. For example, you cannot retrieve output parameters until after you call Close.*